# GeoDjango PointField input

Tags: django, point, geodjango

It can be a stupid question, but I haven't find out the answer. 
I implemented GeoDjango and a PointField, so in the admin page I tried to create a new object, but it always tells me that the coordinates are incorrect, on the page there is a field like a textfield, but I don't know which format is right for coordinates.

I have to set this field hidden to insert coordinates from google maps, but if I don't know the format... it cuold be difficult.

Thnks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't enabled the [GeoDjango admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geographic-admin).  If you enable the admin, you should be able to edit the field using a point and click interface.

If you do want to edit it manually with the coordinates, try using [Well Known Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).  Basically, it is of the form `POINT(-96.1 45.2)`.